# .next() and .prev() in ul li responsive view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tab panel and I want to put a next and prev in responsive view. Like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-friendly-Responsive-Navigation-Plugin-Swipe-Navigation/ (resize your browser)

I tried to do this but I have no luck. I couldn't work my script correctly. I also tried the script from the link above, but still not working.

How to do this? or How to fix my current code? Or there's an easy way to do this? Please help me.

[My code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzOPrL)

```
<ul class="tabs swipenavigation js-swipenavigation'">
   <li class="active"><span class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-locator">Tab 1</span></li>
   <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 2</span></li>
   <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 3</span></li>
  <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 4</span></li>
  <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 5</span></li>
  <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 6</span></li>
  <li><span  id="partner-store" class="icons-tabbed icon-icon-tab-howto">Tab 7</span></li>
  <a class='next' href='#'>
    <i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>
  </a>
  <a class='back' href='#'>
    <i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can add slick slider or any other slider for navigation, it support responsive view
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @SuperUser but I want only to have a next and prev navigation in responsive view