# Jquery scrolling multiple making li tag active

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I show it as an example immediately .

```
<li id="1" class="menu select">Test</li>
<li id="2" class="menu select">Test</li>
<li id="3" class="menu active">Test</li>
<li id="4" class="menu">Test</li>
<li id="5" class="menu">Test</li>
```

**Active Add addclass to previous select for class**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean from active? You mean what is visible for users?! Please provide more information

Comment: I mean addclass

Comment: $( "li.active" ).nextAll();

$( "li.active" ).prevAll();

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean!

Comment: your question title is telling something else and it confuses everybody.

Comment: https://codepen.io/oktaykose/pen/eEzqrz

Comment: Use `$(".active").prevAll().addBack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.active").prevAll().addClass('active-prev');
  $("li.active").nextAll().addClass('active-next');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f00;
}

.active-next {
  color: #0F0;
}

.active-prev {
  color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="1" class="menu select">Test</li>
<li id="2" class="menu select">Test</li>
<li id="3" class="menu active">Test</li>
<li id="4" class="menu">Test</li>
<li id="5" class="menu">Test</li>
```

Is something like this you need?

Comment: I would like to select in the example before it is active 
 https://codepen.io/oktaykose/pen/eEzqrz

Comment: So in your example, whenever you are adding active class, you must be having/knowing that element before adding active class. Select it before adding active class.

Comment: This is my main problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the below link will help you in understanding your problem.

```
<ul id="navlist">
   <li id="home"><a class="nav" href="home">Home</a></li>
   <li id="about"><a class="nav" href="about-us">About Us</a></li>
   <li id="test"><a class="nav" href="test">test page </a></li>
</ul>

$('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from being followed
   $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   var $first = $('li:first', 'ul');
   var $last = $('li:last', 'ul');
   var $selected = $(".selected");
   $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
   console.log($first, 'last:- ',$last, 'next item:- ',$next)
});

// Css
.nav { color: green; }
.selected { color: red; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hnagarkoti/wo8wmwL1/

[jQuery select ul li items with next prev buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707001/jquery-select-ul-li-items-with-next-prev-buttons)