# Link to several sliders on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I always used the script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707287/5765312) from @Sushanth -- to slide images on single pages. It's perfect.

The problem, it only works on one slider per page, now I'm in a project where I have to place different small sliders associated with buttons and obviously, it doesn't work, or rather, only the first one works. It has taken me a long time to understand the script, as I have read in other answers, I guess it's something about assigning a different ID to each slider, but I cannot find the solution.

In the example snippet, the round button links to the first slider, the one that works. The square button links to the second slider (with three slides) but it doesn't work. Since sliders are links, each slider has its own set of next, prev, and close buttons.

```js
var $first = $('li:first', 'ul'),
  $last = $('li:last', 'ul');


// Have the first and last li's set to a variable
$("#next").click(function() {
  var $next,
    $selected = $(".selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If next li is empty , get the first
  $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $next.addClass('selected');
  // hides target       
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var $prev,
    $selected = $(".selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If prev li is empty , get the last
  $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $prev.addClass('selected');
  // hides target       
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});
```

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pre,
.post,
.fstbutton,
.scndbutton,
.BACK {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  color: #C2C6D2;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.fstbutton:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f111";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.scndbutton:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f0c8";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.pre:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f060";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.post:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f061";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.BACK:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f00d";
  font-weight: 900;
}


/* pop-up */

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ecf0fa;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup:target {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein 0, 2s;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  height: 100%;
}


/*SLIDER*/

.SLIDER {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.4rem;
  right: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  display: none;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.selected,
.linked:last-child {
  display: block;
}


/*FIN SLIDER*/

.yl {
  background: yellow;
}

.br {
  background: brown;
}

.bl {
  background: blue;
}

.pi {
  background: pink;
}

.re {
  background: red;
}

.or {
  background: orange;
}

.cy {
  background: cyan;
}

.gr {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
<a class="fstbutton" href="#firstslider"></a>
<a class="scndbutton" href="#scndslider"></a>



<div id="firstslider" class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li class="linked yl">
      <h3>Yellow</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="linked bl">
      <h3>Blue</h3></li>
    <li class="linked br">
      <h3>Brown</h3></li>
    <li class="linked cy">
      <h3>Cyan</h3></li>
    <li class="linked gr">
      <h3>Green</h3></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="SLIDER">
    <div id="prev" class="pre"></div>
    <div id="next" class="post"></div>
    <div class="BACK" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="scndslider" class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li class="linked pi">
      <h3>Pink</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="linked re">
      <h3>Red</h3></li>
    <li class="linked or">
      <h3>Orange</h3></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="SLIDER">
    <div id="prev2" class="pre"></div>
    <div id="next2" class="post"></div>
    <div class="BACK" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have duplicate IDs, `<div id="prev"` and `<div id="next"`. either switch to `class` or call them `prev2` and `next2`

Comment: this fixes the problem, post it as an answer. The new issue is that I need to put the same slides quantity on each slider

Comment: did it right now.

Comment: You should format your code and use a good editor, or run it through a validator. You're missing many closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to bind `click` events using different IDs for `prev` and `next` element.

Here I used `#prev2` and `#next2`, and duplicated your functions, limiting each set of buttons to `#firstslider` and `#scndslider`

```js
var $first = $('#firstslider li:first'),
  $last = $('#firstslider li:last');

var $first2 = $('#scndslider li:first'),
  $last2 = $('#scndslider li:last');


// Have the first and last li's set to a variable
$("#next").click(function() {
  var $next,
    $selected = $("#firstslider .selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If next li is empty , get the first
  $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $next.addClass('selected');
  // hides target         
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var $prev,
    $selected = $("#firstslider .selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If prev li is empty , get the last
  $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $prev.addClass('selected');
  // hides target         
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});


// Have the first and last li's set to a variable
$("#next2").click(function() {
  var $next,
    $selected = $("#scndslider .selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If next li is empty , get the first
  $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first2;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $next.addClass('selected');
  // hides target         
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});

$("#prev2").click(function() {
  var $prev,
    $selected = $("#scndslider .selected");

  // get the selected item
  // If prev li is empty , get the last
  $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last2;
  $selected.removeClass("selected");
  $prev.addClass('selected');
  // hides target         
  $('li').removeClass("linked");
});
```

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pre,
.post,
.fstbutton,
.scndbutton,
.BACK {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  color: #C2C6D2;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.fstbutton:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f111";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.scndbutton:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f0c8";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.pre:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f060";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.post:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f061";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.BACK:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
  content: "\f00d";
  font-weight: 900;
}


/* pop-up */

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ecf0fa;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup:target {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein 0, 2s;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  height: 100%;
}


/*SLIDER*/

.SLIDER {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.4rem;
  right: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  display: none;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.selected,
.linked:last-child {
  display: block;
}


/*FIN SLIDER*/

.yl {
  background: yellow;
}

.br {
  background: brown;
}

.bl {
  background: blue;
}

.pi {
  background: pink;
}

.re {
  background: red;
}

.or {
  background: orange;
}

.cy {
  background: cyan;
}

.gr {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
<a class="fstbutton" href="#firstslider"></a>
<a class="scndbutton" href="#scndslider"></a>



<div id="firstslider" class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li class="linked yl">
      <h3>Yellow</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="linked bl">
      <h3>Blue</li>
    <li class="linked br">
      <h3>Brown</li>
    <li class="linked cy">
      <h3>Cyan</li>
    <li class="linked gr">
      <h3>Green</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="SLIDER">
    <div id="prev" class="pre"></div>
    <div id="next" class="post"></div>
    <div class="BACK" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="scndslider" class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li class="linked pi">
      <h3>Pink</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="linked re">
      <h3>Red</li>
    <li class="linked or">
      <h3>Orange</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="SLIDER">
    <div id="prev2" class="pre"></div>
    <div id="next2" class="post"></div>
    <div class="BACK" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but there's an error. After passing slides, closing the slider and opening the other one, shows two slides together https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxW98.png :-(

Comment: I forgot to duplicate `$first` and `$last`. just edited the answer adding `$first2` and `$last2`

Comment: I posted an error in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73454027/5765312)